# Show that cardinality of whole number is equal to cardinality of Natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Proof for cardinality of natural numbers is equal to the cardinality of whole numbers

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What are "whole" numbers? [Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)?

Comment: Hint : 

$f: \mathbb{N}\to \Bbb{Z}$ defined by $$f(n)=\begin{cases} \frac{n}{2} &\text{ } n :even \\\frac{-(n+1) }{2}&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Comment: You should explicitly define each set because "whole number" is primarily used colloquially (hence not always has a fixed meaning) and in lower school levels (and likely with various meanings around the world), whereas "natural number" is well-known to have two commonly used meanings (see 2nd paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number)).